# Selenium Webdriver_Not able to click on link given into column

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to write a Selenium web driver. I'm using eclipse and trying to locate a link available in next column. In each row I have different link. For example in my employee data table I have 2 columns and 10 rows in one page. The first column contains the name of person and second column contains its employee ID (ID is a hyperlink). I'm trying to select the hyperlink of any employee but I'm not able to do it.

I have below the HTML code and sample script.

```
<span id="37">

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="FC_Schema.1021.WIP" type="DataCheckingList" name="FC_Schema.1021.WIP">

<input id="baseurl" type="hidden" value="/Web/" name="baseurl">

<input id="hdnDcCnt" type="hidden" value="13" name="hdnDcCnt">

<input id="PageNo" type="hidden" value="1" name="PageNo">

<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">

<style type="text/css">

<div id="DataCheckingLoad">

<div id="SupplyChainTabs">

<div id="gbo" class="InnerAlertsTabs">

<table id="one" class="draggable" width="100%">

<thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td valign="top" align="center">

<td valign="top">

<td valign="top">

<a onclick="return ButtonClick(this,'TxnyD.Communities.2.1','Org.2000476_Product.THQS|SMS|Questionnaire.WIP_Questionnaire_TxnyD.Communities.2.1_THQS_TxnyD.Operationaloffice.1.2');" href="#f">Axiom 
Process LLC</a>

<div class="country-name">

<div class="CompanyInfoContactLinks">

</td>

<td valign="top">

THQS

<div class="clear"> </div>

<a id="Org.2000476_Product.THQS|SMS|Questionnaire.WIP_Questionnaire_TxnyD.Communities.2.1_THQS_TxnyD.Operationaloffice.1.2" onclick="RedirectToQuestionnairePage(id)" href="#">THQS</a>

<div class="clear"> </div>

</td>
```

In the above code first column contains *company name* i.e "Axiom 
Process LLC" and second column contains *company subcription name* i.e."THQS". I have to select the THQS link of company "Axiom Process LLC"

Selenium script designed for it as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Web");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys("Gbouser.1");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Login']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Task')]")).click();   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Data Checking')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Axiom")).findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'THQS')]")).click();
}
```

So basically these are dynamic tables and each time it will have different records. How can select the link available in column?

I also tried below script as well:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("*[id^='CLS'][id$='Demolition Limited']")).findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'THQS')])[3]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow. Before answering your question, just a few pointers. Think that you had a downvote 'cause you didn't format your question well. Otherwise a perfectly legal question, and you would receive help much earlier.

Secondly, don't ever put the real Web site address, username and password :). I was able to login, and understand exactly what you need, but a malicious guy could do bad wonders there.

To answer your question, instead of the line that is causing you problems, try this

```
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    TablePageObject tablePageObject = PageFactory.initElements(driver, TablePageObject.class);
    tablePageObject.clickLink("Axiom");
```

Where TablePageObject is

```
public class TablePageObject {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = "table tr")
    private List<WebElement> allTableRows; // find all the rows of the table

    public TablePageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void clickLink(String companyName) {
        for(WebElement row : allTableRows) {
            List<WebElement> links = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("a"));
            // the first link by row is the company name, the second is link to be clicked
            if (links.get(0).getText().contains(companyName)) {
                links.get(3).click();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

An explanation, TablePageObject class will be your programmatic handle for the dynamic table you're trying to control. It follows a page factory pattern of selenium, which I heartly recommend, and you can learn more here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

It basically keeps a collection of rows of your table, which more or less looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">
        // irelevant
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        // irelevant
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <a>Axiom Process LLC</a>
        <a>company details</a>
        <a>web details</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <a>THQS</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="display: none">
       // irelevant
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        //irelevant
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        // irelevant
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

You collect all the links from the table, check the company name against the first link, and if matched, click the fourth link,

Hope it helps, best,

by the way, I've masked your password in the question

Comment: Excellent !! its working Now. Really appreciated your valuable guidance for new user like me . i will keep in mind all the suggestion. thank you sir.